# Mailgun API call "Mailing list member not found"

Tags: vb.net, api, mailgun

I get the "Mailing list member not found" when I call a DELETE, I then tested a PUT, to try an update the subscription setting, and I get the same message.

But when I try to add someone with a POST to the list with the same email address I get a "Address already exists" message....using same API, and structure:

```
Public Function RemoveMember(ListEmail As String, EmailAddress As String) As RestResponse
    Dim client As New RestClient()
    client.BaseUrl = "https://api.mailgun.net/v2"
    client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", MailGunAPI)
    Dim request As New RestRequest()
    request.Resource = "lists/{list}/members/{member}"
    request.AddParameter("list", ListEmail, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
    request.AddParameter("member", EmailAddress)
    request.Method = Method.DELETE
    Return client.Execute(request)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the member parameter the parameter type needs to be specified as UrlSegment:

```
request.AddParameter("member", EmailAddress, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.  Documentation was a little unclear here.